# Usar la misma conexion en el .dbml Linq to sql C# para evitar Conexiones sleeping

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dbml

Tengo un Archivo .dbml donde hago las conexiones para mi proyecto en c#,
y tengo un metodo para crear la conexion. cuando realizo mis consultas a la BD
solo utilizo la variable estatica y todo bien reutilizando la conexion a esa BD.

```
private static DataClassesDataContext _dataContext;

//Enlaze de Conexion con el dblm 
public void ConectarDataContext()
{
  _dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext(string de conexion);     
}
```

Pero cada vez que cambio de BD veo en el Pool de Conexiones que mantiene la conexion anterior en
sleeping, entonces si cambio de varias veces de BD se acumulan esas conexiones.

que podria hacer para reutilizar la primera conexion, y apesar de cambiar de BD, no me cree otra conexion.

Estoy trabajando con una aplicacion de windows form en c#, ya tenia este codigo para hacer la conexion con el DataContext

```
private DataClassesDataContext DataContext
{
    get
    {
        return (_dataContext = newDataClassesDataContext(Conexion.conexion));
    }

}
```

pero presentaba un problema xq cada vez que consultaba en la BD me creaba una nueva conexion, entonces pasaba que el usuario tenias varias conexiones sleeping en una misma base de datos, al hacer static el dataContext y traerlo cada vez que lo necesitaba me evite ese problema.

```
private static DataClassesDataContext _dataContext;

 //Constructor para Retornar la Conexion
 public DataClassesDataContext DataContexto
 {
    get
    {
       return _dataContext;
    }

 }

//Enlaze de Conexion con el dblm 
public void ConectarDataContext()
{
  _dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext(string de conexion);     
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Aparentemente es mala idea declarar el contexto de base de datos como static (sigue [este hilo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d64ed39-2dd0-4ec2-9f82-664278d659c3/using-static-dbcontext?forum=adodotnetentityframework)). Qué quieres lograr con eso? Dale una mirada a esta [respuesta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#dbcontext-pooling), también. Una pregunta, estás intentando que la conexión se abra y esté viva mientras la aplicación está abierta? Si es así... Por qué?

Comment: Gracias, @Arriel por tu respuesta, soy nuevo en esta plataforma, peor deje una respuesta a mi pregunta para aclarar un poco por que la hice static, garcias por la ayuda